# Using Qualtrics: (How) can I turn off language menu bar and display two decimal numbers?

Tags: qualtrics

Right now I face two problems that I am not sure about whether they can be solved as desired inside the Qualtrics system or not:

- I have 3 language versions of my survey, hence, Qualtrics would display a menu bar on top of the survey to each participant to choose between languages. I don't want people to change language, though, as it might have an effect on their behavior. Can I turn off the menu bar or should I use distinct surveys and delete alternative translations?
- My survey calculates performance-based payoffs such as 1 € or 0.10 € and displays them after each trial to the participant. Due to certain circumstances, a 3 decimals amount such as 1.121 € might be calculated which I got rid of using `$e{ round( e://Field/pay * e://Field/factor , 2 ) }`.
  However, for obvious reasons, 10 cents are displayed as `0.1 €` and not as in real world, `0.10 €`, which I would prefer. I tried to add `.toFixed(2);` to the respective line of code, `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'balance', balance + pay ).toFixed(2);`, but then that particular answer option does not react anymore. Maybe there is a syntax or logical error in that approach? Anything else to try?

Answer (score 3):

To hide the language selector on all pages, put the following in the header or footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
    $$('.LanguageSelectorContainer').first().hide();
});
</script>
```

Yes, your .toFixed code would cause a syntax error. Try:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'balance', (balance + pay).toFixed(2) );
```